# Defining Objects in loops

Tags: java, instantiation

im stuck with the dilemma of defining multiple objects with different names, i would like to define an amount of objects according to an amount i need taken from another part of the program

the part object(i) isnt correct, i just put it there to illustrate my problem

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= amountOfObjectsNeeded; i++){

        someclass object(i) = new someclass();
    }
```

does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you do the Oracle Java Tutorial ... or take a Java programming course.  You can't learn to program properly by trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an array in this case:

```
Someclass[] array = new Someclass[amountOfObjectsNeeded];
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfObjectsNeeded; i++) {
    array[i] = new Someclass();
}
```

Note how the loop starts from 0 rather than 1--arrays in Java are indexed starting at 0.

Comment: As an addition to the above answer, please take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html in case you want to know more about arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a **map**, if you want to assign names/ids to your objects and access them later on by those names:

```
 Map<String, SomeClass> map = new HashMap<String, SomeClass>();
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
    String name = getNameForObjectNr(i);
    map.put(name, new SomeClass());
 }

 // later on

 SomeClass someClass = map.get(someName);  // to read an instance from the map
```